# Spring Hibernate cannot access Entity that is in DB in service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a SceneService that is used to save a scene and create another entity in the DB, these are both saved via JPA repositories

```
@Service("sceneService")
public class SceneService extends BaseService {

  ...
 ProcessingJob processingJob = new ProcessingJob();
 processingJobRepository.save(processingJob);

  sceneRepository.save(scene);
...
}
```

Later I have a job that picks the processingJobs

```
@Slf4j
@Transactional
@Scope("singleton")
@Service
public class ProcessVideoJob extends AmazonService {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)
    public void start(){

        for(ProcessingJob job : processingJobRepository.findAllByStatus(ProcessingJob.ProcessJobStatus.NEW.asInt()))
            process(job);

    }

    public void process(ProcessingJob job){
        Scene scene = sceneRepository.getOne(job.getId());
        log.info(scene.toString());
    }

}
```

That scene is always null.

***javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find co.example.model.Scene with id 1***

The scene is in the DB at this time. If I restart server etc it still can't access this scene. I've tried logging in and out etc as well.

Why can't this service access the Scene entity?

Comment: Can it find any records at all?

Comment: It can in other places. Just not in this class.

Comment: Please provide code on `SceneRepostiroy#getOne` and  `SceneRepostiroy#save` and also make sure you have a scene with the id = 1 (not any scene)

Comment: Thanks. They are JPAs, yes the scene with ID 1 is in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that one of the oneToMany relationships in Scene had be nulled from another process, and it stopped the Scene getting returned. Not sure why.